# How to use TCP connection of an activity in another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, tcp

I have a TCP connection class that works in my main activity. When a button is clicked, I am starting a new activity. Main activity still remains connected to the server when the new one is launched. I want to use this connection in the new activity to send a message to the server. Is there a way to use this connection in the new activity or should I close the existing connection and connect again in the new activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a static singleton to hold the TCP connection object (`Socket`):

```
public class SocketHolder {
      private Socket socket;
      public Socket getSocket() { return socket; }
      public void setSocket(Socket socket) {this.socket = socket;}

      private static final SocketHolder holder = new SocketHolder();
      public static SocketHolder getInstance() {return holder;}
    }
```

Set it in one activity like this:

```
SocketHolder.getInstance().setSocket(mySocket);
```

and get it in the other like this:

```
Socket mySocket = SocketHolder.getInstance().getSocket();
```

Alternatively you can of course use a Singleton to hold your Connection class.